# C# Reflection - Populate class properties from delimited strings using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, casting, system.reflection

I am trying to populate a class using data retrieved from an irregular CSV formatted file.
I am able to get the data from the file, determine if the property values are present in the file, and create objects from the retrieved data.

When attempting to populate the class properties, I have tried:

```
this.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(this, newProp);
```

**...resulting in the exception:**

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SharpCodingTestApp.Bar]]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SharpCodingTestApp.Bar]'.'

and...

```
this.GetType().InvokeMember(propName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, this, new object[] { newProp });
```

**...resulting in the exception:**

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method
>   'SharpCodingTestApp.Bar' not found.'

Here is the code I am currently running:

```
public class FooBar
{
    private string _configFile;

    public Foo PropFoo { get; get; }
    public List<Bar> PropBar { get; set; }

    public void Load()
    {
        List<object> props = new List<object>();

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_configFile) != true)
        {
            //Does the config file contain all of the required settings?
            if (ConfigFileContainsRoomConfigSettings(_configFile))
            {
                //Get the information we need from the file.
                string[] configLines = GetConfigLines(_configFile);

                foreach (var line in configLines)
                {
                    var propName = line.Split(", ")[0].Trim(' ');
                    var newProp = CreatePropertyObejct(propName, line);
                    this.GetType().InvokeMember(propName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, this, new object[] { newProp });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private object CreatePropertyObejct(string paramPropertyName, string paramPropertyConfigString)
    {
        var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(paramPropertyName);
        if (prop.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("list") == true)
        {
            var listType = typeof(List<>);
            var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(prop.PropertyType);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
        }
        else
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, paramPropertyConfigString, ',');
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of the data in the file:

```
Foo, FooVal1, FooVal2
Bar, BarVal1, BarVal2, BarVal3, BarVal4
Bar, BarVal1, BarVal2, BarVal3, BarVal4
```

The first value in each delimited string contains the Property name for which the data belongs.
Bar has multiple entries in the file to represent each of the objects in the list.

How do I resolve the exception(s) and is there a better way to go about doing what I am trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing reflection code, don't resort to string comparisons. And try to pre-build and cache everything you need. However, finding the right way can be difficult if you don't know what questions to ask.

Your first error is happening because `prop.PropertyType` is already a `List<T>`, so `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(prop.PropertyType)`, is defining a `List<List<T>>`.

Is the input data actually a csv? Can the data contain quotes, comma's and line feeds? Then `.Split(", ")` is not going to cut it. You'll need to find / implement a proper c# parser.

I'm not really clear on what are you trying to do with each of the other csv columns?

Comment: The CSV file holds a series of settings. Because each setting is different, the file is irregular instead of containing the same format on every line as is standard with a delimited format.  Ordinarily I would be doing this with JSON and use the Newtonsoft library.  Unfortunately, I have specific requirements dictating I use a comma separated values for the settings in the file.

Comment: If all else fails, manually build a ```Dictionary<string,Action<IEnumerable<string>>>``` for handling each property...

Comment: The primary class object contains properties that are to be instantiated and populated with the values in the file.  All of the properties are custom classes or Lists of custom classes.

Comment: I have resolved the List<List<T>> issue.  Now I get: `System.MissingMethodException: 'Method 'SharpCodingTestApp.Config.SettingA' not found.'`

The exception is showing the correct property which is defined as `List<CustomSettingA> SettingA { get; set; }`